# Prove divergence of recursive sequence $a_0 = 0, a_{n+1} = a_{n} +1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, recurrence-relations

I have to prove $a_0 = 0, a_{n+1} = a_{n} +1 (n \ge 0)$ is a divergent sequence using the definition.

I've noticed that this sequence should also be described simply as $a_n=n$. Shall I simplify the recursive form into $a_n=n$ first or it's unnecessary? How shall I proceed from here? I've seen many examples showing how to prove a sequence with boundaries it is divergent, but I failed to apply the ideas to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What definition is meant?

Comment: A sequence which is not convergent is divergent. And convergent is "$\forall\varepsilon>0$ $\exists N\in\Bbb R$ such that $|x_n -\mathscr a|<\varepsilon$ 
$\forall n \in \Bbb N$ with $n>N$, then the sequence converges to a".

Comment: @parsiad Yes, I think I missed that... Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a_n \rightarrow a \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $a=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_{n}+1=a+1$ and hence $0=1$. Woops!

Comment: I didn't understand the "$\lim a_{n}+1$" part. Is there a method that can go without involving $lim$? So there's no need to convert the recursive form into $a_n=n$?

Comment: $\lim_n x_n$ just refers to the limit of a sequence $(x_n)_n$. I am simply taking the limit of both sides of the equation $a_{n+1}=a_n+1$. Both $(a_{n+1})_n$ and $(a_n+1)_n$ are sequences in their own right. The first has the limit $a$, while the latter has the limit $a+1$ (convince yourself of this).

Comment: Fred's answer above is also completely reasonable. You've already convinced yourself that $a_n=n$ (this is unbounded). All that you have to do is convince yourself that a convergent sequence is bounded, if you want to take Fred's approach.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Although I think I still have to write the proof contradicting the assumption that this sequence were convergent using the definition.

Answer (score 1):

A convergent sequence is bounded. $(a_n) =(n) $ is not.